# Handle Change not working in React Select

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, event-handling, onchange

I would like to firstly inform am a very newbie to React development.  Well, am trying to develop a form for updating the value. Everything works fine except the update of the select field.

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import TweakDataForm from "./TweakDataForm";
import {tweakDataUpdateActions} from "./modules/tweakDataUpdateAction"



function TabContainer(props) {
  return (
    <Typography component="div" style={{ padding: 8 * 3 }}>
      {props.children}
    </Typography>
  );
}

TabContainer.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};



const styles = () => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: '#E2E5DE'
  }
});

class OrderServiceTabScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: 0,
  };
  
  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };
  

  render() {
    const { classes,orderTabDataCollections } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static" color="default">
          <Tabs
            value={value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            indicatorColor="primary"
            textColor="primary"
            variant="scrollable"
            scrollButtons="auto"
          >

            {Object.keys(orderTabDataCollections).map(keyz =>
            <Tab key={keyz} label={keyz.toUpperCase()} />
   
    )}
            
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>

        <TabContainer key='0' >
                 <TweakDataForm 
                 key='0' 
                 tweakDataCollection= {orderTabDataCollections['xtd']}
                 handleUpdateData={this.props.tweakDataUpdateActionsRequest}

                 />
              </TabContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
...state
});
const matchDispatchToProps = {
  tweakDataUpdateActionsRequest: tweakDataUpdateActions.request
};

OrderServiceTabScreen.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};



export default withStyles(styles)(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    matchDispatchToProps
  )(OrderServiceTabScreen))
```

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import SaveIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Save';
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";

import { Form, withFormik } from "formik";
// import * as Yup from "yup";

const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    width: 200,
  },
  dense: {
    marginTop: 19,
  },
  menu: {
    width: 200,
  },
  fab: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: theme.spacing.unit * 5,
    right: theme.spacing.unit * 10,
  }
});

const has_hfp_type_collections = [
  {
    value: 'HX40-D',
    label: 'HX40-D',
  },
  {
    value: 'HX10=D',
    label: 'HX10-D',
  },
  {
    value:'',
    label:'NA'
  }
];

const hfp_type_collections = [
  {
    value: 'TX40-U',
    label: 'TX40-U',
  },
  {
    value: 'TX10-U',
    label: 'TX10-U',
  },
  {
    value:'',
    label:'NA'
  }
];


const formikEnhancer = withFormik({
   }),
  mapPropsToValues: (state) => ({
    hysicalName:state.tweakDataCollection.hysicalName?state.tweakDataCollection.physicalName:"",
    hashfpType:state.tweakDataCollection.hashfpType?state.tweakDataCollection.hashfpType:"",
    address:state.tweakDataCollection.address?state.tweakDataCollection.address:"",
    zocId:state.tweakDataCollection.zocId?state.tweakDataCollection.zocId:"",
    hfpType:state.tweakDataCollection.hfpType?state.tweakDataCollection.hfpType:"",
    powerSupply2:state.tweakDataCollection.powerSupply2?state.tweakDataCollection.powerSupply2:"",
    powerSupply1:state.tweakDataCollection.powerSupply1?state.tweakDataCollection.powerSupply1:"",
    


  }),
  handleSubmit: (values, bag) => {
    console.log('handleSubmit..')
    console.log(values)
    console.log(bag)
  }
});




class TweakDataForm extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    console.log(props);
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      values: props.tweakDataCollection
    };
  }


  render() {
    const { classes,
      tweakDataCollection,
      // handleUpdateData,
      handleChange,
      handleSubmit,
      values,
     } = this.props;

     const handlehfpTypeChange = (event,name) => {
      const newValues = {...values, hfpType: event.target.value}
      this.setState({values: newValues});
      console.log(values);
    };
    
    const handlehashfpTypeChange = (event,name) => {
      const newValues = {...values, hashfpType: event.target.value}
      this.setState({values: newValues});
      console.log(values);
    };
    
    return ( <Form className={classes.container}>

      {tweakDataCollection && Object.keys(tweakDataCollection).map(function(keyz, index) {
        if (keyz === 'address'){
            return <TextField
            id={keyz}
            label={keyz}
            style={{ margin: 8 }}
            fullWidth
            key={keyz}
            name={keyz}
            value={values.address}
            margin="normal"
            onChange={handleChange}
            InputLabelProps={{
              shrink: true,
            }}
          />

        }
        else if(keyz==='hfpType'){

          return <TextField
          id={keyz}
          name={keyz}
          key={keyz}
          select
          label={keyz}
          onChange={e => handlehfpTypeChange(e,keyz)}
          className={classes.textField}
          value={values.sfpType}
          SelectProps={{
            MenuProps: {
              className: classes.menu,
            },
          }}
          margin="normal"
        >
          {hfp_type_collections.map(option => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.label}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
        }
        else if (keyz ==='hashfpType'){

          return <TextField
          id={keyz}
          name={keyz}
          key={keyz}
          select
          label={keyz}
          onChange={e => handlehashfpTypeChange(e,keyz)}
          className={classes.textField}
          value={values.hashfpType}
          SelectProps={{
            MenuProps: {
              className: classes.menu,
            },
          }}
          margin="normal"
        >
          {has_hfp_type_collections.map(option => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.label}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>

        } 
        else if(keyz === 'hysicalName') {
          return <TextField
          id={keyz}
          name={keyz}
          key={keyz}
          label={keyz}
          className={classes.textField}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={values.physicalName}
          margin="normal"
        /> 
        }

        else if (keyz === 'locId'){
          return <TextField
          id={keyz}
          name={keyz}
          key={keyz}
          label={keyz}
          className={classes.textField}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={values.locId}
          margin="normal"
        /> 

        }
        else if(keyz === 'powerSupply1'){
          return <TextField
          id={keyz}
          name={keyz}
          key={keyz}
          label={keyz}
          className={classes.textField}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={values.powerSupply1}
          margin="normal"
        /> 

        }
        else if(keyz === 'powerSupply2'){
          return <TextField
          id={keyz}
          name={keyz}
          key={keyz}
          label={keyz}
          className={classes.textField}
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={values.powerSupply2}
                    margin="normal"
        /> 

        }
           
          })}

          <div className="clearfix">
          <Fab className={classes.fab} onClick={handleSubmit} color='secondary'>
          <SaveIcon />
          </Fab>
          </div>
          </Form>    
    );
  }
}

TweakDataForm.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(formikEnhancer(TweakDataForm));
```

All other fields are changing their values but the select fields are not. It is not updating the object with updated values. Could some help me to identify what is missing in the implementation for reflecting the change?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're passing two parameters to the function instead of one and you can try using a switch statement to make the code readable.

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log("Fruit Selected!!");
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  }

  <select value={this.state.fruit} onChange={handleChange}>
     {options.map((option) => (
        <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
      ))}
  </select>
```

Comment: What might be the reason for not updating the props  using this code `const handleSfpTypeChange = (event,name) => {
       console.log(this.state);
      const newValues = {...values, sfpType: event.target.value}
      console.log('NEW VALUSES')
      console.log(newValues)
      this.setState({values: newValues});
      console.log('OLD VALUES')
      console.log(values);
    };`